Euler's Tower sequence
Let $\alpha\in [0,\infty]$ and let $a_0=\alpha$ and $a_{n+1}=\alpha^{a_n}$
for which values of $\alpha$ doe the sequence converge? And where?
\ My attempt: 
Clearly for $\alpha>1$ the sequence goes to $\infty$, since $\alpha$'s exponent is greater than 1. For $\alpha=1$ the sequence is fixed at $1$ for any $n$. For what concernes the interval $[0,1]$ my initial claim was that it didn't converge to any specific value but through brute forcing some data on Octave i found out that, clearly, i was wrong. Now that i have the correct claim to show: let $$x_\alpha=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha^{\alpha^{\alpha^{\alpha^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$$ In particular $x_\alpha$ needs to be a fixed point for $a_n$ and since the function $$f(x)=x^x\quad x\in[0,1]$$ is a contractive function we can use the Bananch-Cacciopoli theorem to say that for any value of $\alpha$, $x_\alpha$ is the sole fixed point.
Now i want to see what exactly $x_\alpha$ is. It must satisfy the rule: $$x_\alpha=\alpha^{x_\alpha}$$ Taking the logarithm from both sides we get:
$$\log{x_\alpha}=\log{\alpha^{x_\alpha}}\Rightarrow \alpha \log{x_\alpha}=x_\alpha\log{\alpha}\Rightarrow \frac{x_\alpha}{\alpha}=\frac{\log{x_\alpha}}{\log{\alpha}}$$
$$e^{\frac{x_\alpha}{\alpha}}=e^{\frac{\log{x_\alpha}}{\log{\alpha}}}$$
But here I got stuck. Anybody knows if my reasoning is flawed and how to fix it. Or is there another way to solve this? Thanks
EDIT: Thanks to my uni professor I found out that probably the correct function that describes the recurrence is actually: $f(x)=\sqrt[x]{x}$, because the derivatives are more in line with the rest of the calculations.

a friend of mine found out that my calculations are flawed anyways, don't mind them.

From checking where $\left\lvert f'(x_\alpha)\right\rvert<1$ if $f(x)=\alpha^x$, I get that $\alpha\in[0.067,1]$ to $3\mathrm{sf}$. I don't know what the exact value of the $0.067$ is but that is where $x_\alpha\ln\alpha>-1$.
